# Custom attribute does not work with outputcache attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, attributes

I have a action like this:

```
[Route("~/blog-{id}")]
[Count("Blog","id")]
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "id", Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient)]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Details(int id)
```

I also have a simple class as below:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CountAttribute :FilterAttribute,IActionFilter
{
    private readonly string _id;
    private readonly string _name;

    public CountAttribute( string name, string id)
    {
        _id = id;
        _name = name;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var value = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(_id).AttemptedValue;
        if (value == null)
        {
            return;
        }


        string path =
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.MapPath(string.Format("~/App_Data/{0}_{1}.txt", _name, value));


        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(path, "1");
        }
        else
        {
            var readText = File.ReadAllText(path);

            var viewsInt = Int32.Parse(readText);
            viewsInt++;
            File.WriteAllText(path, viewsInt.ToString());

        }

    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

It's a simple counter class the store number of page views for my actions.
I used a break point on `OnActionExecuting` method to see if it's work properly. It does work great but that's only if i remove `OutPutCache` attribute form my actions. if i don't do that, it will only hit one time and that's when the page is not in cache.

So how can i use `OutPutCache` and also make this class works?

**Update**

I have a `_LoginPartial` in my layout page to show my users info. but using `OutPutCache` it was impassible to make it work correctly.
So i used [DonotPutCache](https://github.com/moonpyk/mvcdonutcaching/) To make this particular issue go away. As the same time this problem also seen to go away too and now this counter is works.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the method is cached, and distributed from where it is cached. Potentially this might not even be the server which initially generated/ served the content. If the requirements of the cache key are met, the server will never know about the request because the entire content will be sent from the cache, so there's no way to increment a counter in this way.

A workaround I can think of is to have a script call in the output of the content which performs a request to some other endpoint with the ID. This other endpoint can then increment the counter for you.

Comment: So using javascript at the end of my page is the only way, right?

Comment: As far as I am aware, yes.